# Ionic Tabs View Caching (Loading old views)

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I got confused that created a new ionic 3 projects with tabs template.

There is two tabs like **Home** & **Booking**

**Home** -> List Hotels (1) -> List Menu (2) -> Order Food (3)-> Payment (4)-> Success Payment redirect to **Bookings** (5)

**Bookings**  -> List the completed bookings (5)

He after successful payment of order I ma redirecting to the user to bookings page (2nd tab actually(5)).

```
let currentIndex = this.navCtrl.getActive().index;
this.navCtrl.push(MyBookingsPage,{animate: true, direction: 'forward'}).then(() => {
   this.navCtrl.remove(currentIndex);
});
```

Then I tap Bookings tab menu from bottom and its loading the bookings page as perfect. But

When I tap on the **Home** tab its loading the Bookings page again and tab **Home** tab its going to the Home page and working perfect.

I need to tap two times to load **Home** page.

Why this coming like this ? Is this due to caching of views ?

I am using **NavController** push method to redirect pages.